# How to print jSON values with loop

Tags: php, json

I am using the following code to print the output of the jSON response but when I try to print

```
echo $obj->HotelListResponse->customerSessionId;  // This is working.

echo $obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary->name; // This is not working.
```

When the response contains only one node then its printing perfectly but when there are multiple nodes with same name then its not printing. I tried using foreach just like the below. I also tried using while loop but still I am unable to print the list of hotel names.

My jSON decoded output is like http://pastebin.com/Fr21DkEk

Total code:

```
$url = "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&currencyCode=AUD&xml=<HotelListRequest><city>Brisbane</city><stateProvinceCode>QLD</stateProvinceCode><countryCode>AU</countryCode><arrivalDate>10/16/2014</arrivalDate><departureDate>10/18/2014</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults></Room></RoomGroup><numberOfResults>25</numberOfResults></HotelListRequest>";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);

foreach($obj as $val) {
echo $val->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $val) {
    echo $val->name . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: How to print only first value without printing all?

Comment: @lock, maybe this:

`$first = true;
foreach($obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $val) {
    if ( $first ) {
      // do something
      $first = false;
    } else {
      // do something
    }
    // do something
}`

Answer (score 1):

`HotelSummary` is an array:

```
echo $val->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary[0]->name;
```

If you want all of the hotel summaries:

```
foreach($obj as $val) {
    foreach($val->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $sum) {
        echo $sum->name;
    }  
}
```

Comment: no, still not working. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I question the json you have posted then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can directly access them inside the foreach. Like this:

```
foreach($obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $val) {
             // ^^
    // since you're interested on just names, you can point it directly on that object, then each of that batch is in `$val`
    echo $val->name . '<br/>';
}

// or start from the parent
foreach($obj as $values) {

    $customerSessionId = $values->customerSessionId;
    echo $customerSessionId . '<hr/>';
    $hotelList = $values->HotelList;
    foreach($hotelList->HotelSummary as $hotelsummary) {
        echo $hotelsummary->name . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: How to print only first value without printing all?

Comment: @lock can you paraphrase? what is your goal? and what is the first value anyway? can you provide more context? its unclear.

Comment: @lock if you want the first value only, you could directly point it out to the first index, or use `break;` after echoing

Comment: @lock sure mate no prob